# Wrong Tap Coordinates After Search in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm pretty sure the answer to my question is simple, but after a couple of hours of beating my head against it, I'm turning to you...

I have a UITableView with a UISearchBar.  Searching seems to work just fine, but when I search and tap a cell, I am getting the IndexPath of the visible cell, not the coordinate of the cell relative to the entire UITableView.

Now, I'm pretty sure my problem is in/around the fact that I am using gestures instead of didSelectRowAtIndex because I need to handle single taps and double taps.  I've attached the gesture recognizers to the view.

The single/double tap recognizers get the selected table cell with this:

```
CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
```

My UITableView is sized to show about 8 rows before needing to scroll.  Without text entered in the UISearchBar, this works fine (both gestures).  If I scroll to row 15 of the UITableView and tap, cellIndexPath gives me back row 15.

However, if I enter a search term that requires the user to scroll, a tap on any cell past the first screen returns me the cellIndexPath of the row relative to its current visible position (meaning that if I scroll to row 10 and position it to the last row of the UITableView, the tap give mew a row index of 8.

So, basically, I'm trying to figure out why the behavior is different when not searching the UITableView vs. when a search term is entered.

Thanks for your help,
Rob

Comment: Why do you need to work with coordinates? Scrolling + coordinates is asking for trouble.

Comment: Using coordinates because I'm dealing with gestures.  In order to get the tapped cell, I have to get the CGPoint in the UITableView first.  I found my solution, however.  I've added it as an answer.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: When you tap a cell your TableViewDelegate methods will fire. They lead you to the exact cell via indexPath. Implementing your own behavior seems dangerous/unnecessary

Comment: You're correct, but from everything I read and what I experienced, didSelectRowAtIndex was intercepting the first tap when I intended to double-tap (I would never get the double-tap).  The solution I found was to use gestures.  Not sure what you mean by dangerous, but I can understand unnecessary if theres a better way to get the double-tap gesture while also using didSelectRowAtIndex.

Comment: Dangerous because it leads to errors like yours. Why do you want your users to double tap? What happens at single tap?

Answer (score 2):

Wow, sometimes writing down the problem leads you to a solution...  Here's what I realized.  I am using the UISearchBar with a UISearchDisplayController.  My rudimentary understanding is the when searching, the UISearchDisplayController replaces the tableView with its own to display the results.  That being the case, my code above was looking at the wrong UITableView when trying to get the tapped cell when searching.  So, I modified the code as follows and all seems well.

```
CGPoint location;
NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath;
if (self.isSearching)
{
    location = [gesture locationInView:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView];
    cellIndexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
}
else
{
    location = [gesture locationInView:self.tableView];
    cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
}
```